# pygame, why it can't show gray scale picture

Tags: numpy, pygame

I am using pygame to show grayscale images. However, it can't show grayscale image, the output is here

[image]

The images are numpy arrays of which shape is 80X80, and the code is here

```py
surf_1 = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(pic_1)
surf_2 = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(pic_2)
surf_3 = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(pic_3)
surf_4 = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(pic_4)

self.screen.blit(surf_1, (120, 40))
self.screen.blit(surf_2, (210, 40))
self.screen.blit(surf_3, (300, 40))
self.screen.blit(surf_4, (390, 40))
```

My question is how can I show real grayscale images instead of the blue-green one.

### Update

Here is the code to convert RGB to grayscale, it is from the Internet, I don't know the exact source, sorry about that.

```py
def rgb2gray(rgb, img_shape):
    gray = np.dot(rgb[..., :3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
    return gray.reshape(*img_shape)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you use to convert the images to grayscale?

Comment: @skrx, I updated the question. If you use matplotlib to show image, if you did add `cmap=plt.cm.gray`, the same issue occurs. `plt.imshow(gray_img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)` can show the grayscale image.

Comment: Check out the `grayscale` function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10693616/6220679).

Comment: @skrx, I don't think it is the grayscale function makes this issue happens. However, if you use `plt.imshow ` function without `cmap=plt.cm.gray`, the same issue occurs again even with `matplotlib`